# Is typecasting on lvalue of operation not allowed?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I have the below code, where i am doing a type cast of integer pointer to void pointer and try to assign char address.

```
void main()
{
   int *ptr;
   char a = 10;
   (void *)ptr = &a;
   printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

I am getting below error, Is there anyway that i can fix this?

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    (void *)ptr = &a;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more natural to do e.g. `ptr = (int *) &a;`?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you use an `int*` to point to a `char`? That might cause problems and undefined behaviors later.

Comment: To elaborate, #define BUFPTR(p) ((void *) p->ptr) is my code, where i use BUFPTR(p)=&a or a=BUFPTR(p). The second one is compiling fine, but the first is throwing the error which i mentioned. I am restricted to modify the macro alone, but not the code.

Comment: That seems like a completely backward way to do this. It's unclear what the big picture is, but it sounds that like the there is a great chance that you run into problems that Joachim warned about, due to misaligned memory access.

Answer (score 4):

```
ptr = (int *)&a ;
```

is more natural but it's not portable. Might give the impression it works on little endian machine (most nowadays) but relies on byte after `&a` being null. Which it's not the case.

I would suggest

```
printf("%d\n", (int)a) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

The cast on lvalue is valid, i.e, `(void *)ptr` itself is valid, but it's not an lvalue anymore. This is called **lvalue conversion**.

The fix, as @Joachim commented:

```
ptr = (int *) &a;
```

Comment: To elaborate, #define BUFPTR(p) ((void *) p->ptr) is my code, where i use BUFPTR(p)=&a or a=BUFPTR(p). The second one is compiling fine, but the first is throwing the error which i mentioned. I am restricted to modify the macro alone, but not the code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **you cannot cast the left operand of the assignment operator** in C.

Also, in your case you could just do it the other way to make your code work:

```
void main()
{
   int *ptr;
   char a = 10;
   ptr = (int*) &a; // this is perfectly fine
   printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

Comment: Code still doesn't *work*. `printf("%d\n", *ptr);` is undefined behaviour for many reasons, including the strict aliasing violation on dereference.

Comment: Note that this answer is a strict aliasing violation.

Answer (score 1):

type cast of of a variable or expression results in r-value.
so  (void *)ptr gives r-value and you are trying to allocate &a to r-value.
it is something like 0x12345=&a which is wrong so you are getting l-value is required.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't match your example - but the answer to your *question* (instead of your example) - is yes - you can.  Here's how:

```
void encode_fixed32(char *buffer,float input) {
  ((float *)buffer)[0]=input;
}

void decode_fixed32(char *buffer) {
  return ((float *)buffer)[0];
}
```

Comment: Your code example has an strict aliasing violations, and possible alignment issues.

Comment: The first function should be written `void encode_float(char *buffer, float input) { memcpy(buffer, &input, sizeof input); }` and the second `float decode_float(char *buffer) { float f; memcpy(&f, buffer, sizeof f); return f; }`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: this answer only works in C++, not C, but might be relevant nevertheless.

You have to cast your lvalue to a reference-to-a-pointer instead of a pointer, and then the assignment will work:

```
void main()
{
   int *ptr;
   char a = 10;
   (void *&)ptr = &a;
   printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

Note the **&** after **void *** . This way you preserve its lvalue-ness and you can assign into it.

However, in this particular case the printf behaviour will still be undefined because you are reinterpreting a char as an int, and even if you assume little endian, you may still have 3 undefined bytes after the byte representing **10**.

A better use case:

```
int a[5];
int *ptr = a + 2; // points to the element with index=2
(char *&)ptr += sizeof(int); // advances the pointer to the next element
```

This is useful e.g. when you are doing a strided for-loop over an array in CUDA or on an embedded device, and you want to cache the exact step in advance to avoid multiplication by 4 every time inside the loop:

```
const int stride = sizeof(int)*step;
int *my_ptr = first_ptr;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    ...
    (char *&)my_ptr += stride;
}
```

Comment: `(void *&)` is not valid C cast expression. You cannot have address-of operator inside the cast parenthesis.

Comment: The ampersand here is not an address-of operator, but a reference specifier. You're right, my answer is not valid in C, only in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be 8 years late to this discussion, but I came across it because I have a similar problem and have found a solution in C. The issue arises because, as others have said, a cast like `(void *)ptr` does not result in an lvalue so you cannot assign to it. But a dereferenced pointer like `*(void **)&ptr` *is* an lvalue. So you could change your code to:

```
void main()
{
   int *ptr;
   char a = 10;
   *(void **)&ptr = &a;
   printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

and this compiles and runs OK, and does what I think you want it to do. It gives odd output because the value output comes partly from uninitialised bytes adjacent to the `char a` variable, so it's a dangerous thing to do, but it is valid C.

[Modified code compiling and running here](https://godbolt.org/z/c3z1jEcdh)

Comment: *it is valid C.*: not really... `*(void **)&ptr = &a;` might work on some systems, but it has undefined behavior as it violates the strict aliasing rule.  Furthermore, passing `*ptr` to `printf` definitely has undefined behavior because `ptr` might not have the proper alignment and reads beyond the end of  the `char` variable `a`.  2 more instances of undefined behavior: `void main()` is not a proper proper prototype for the `main` function and calling `printf` without a valid prototype such as by including `<stdio.h>` also has undefined behavior.